# Why we have to use another kernel source from the server?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm new to develop linux kernel. I have an assignment to write the system call and compile the kernel. During this work, I have to use another kernel source from the server such as kernel.org, and I wonder that why it is needed? Can we compile the original kernel (the local kernel on the running OS) directly?.

Comment: Sure, you can compile any kernel version you want (within reason). I don't know what you mean by "directly"; if you think it's possible to compile a kernel without obtaining the source code, you are wrong. Why don't you ask whoever gave you the assignment?

Comment: A "kernel running on a server" doesn't need, and probably doesn't have, source on the server.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that you are confused about:

- A running kernel (this is powering your system)
- The kernel source code that can be used to build a kernel.

A running kernel is usually distributed as a compressed binary file. You can usually find this in the `/boot` directory of your system, and distributed as part of the `linux` package.

The linux sources that were used to build that kernel are separate, and are usually in a separate package. As an example, ubuntu distributes these in the [`linux-source`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-source) package. If you were to download that package, you'd notice it is just a repackaging of the kernel source code, and you could directly use it in your assignment.